# AngularJS and linked resources -- getting from scope if exists

Tags: angularjs

I have a typical projects/tasks/subtasks CRUD app, and one can navigate from a top level project listing all the way down to a subtask.

All resources are routed, e.g.

`/projects` to get all projects,

`/projects/:id` to get a specific project,

`/projects/:id/tasks` to get all tasks for a specific project, and so on.

I render tasks like so:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <a href="/tasks/{{task.id}}">
      {{task.name}}</a> ...
```

The controller responsible for the `/tasks/:id` route gets the data using the `$routeParams` from the backend API, but I was wondering how to load the task from the *information I already have in the scope I link from*, e.g. something like:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <a href="/tasks/{{task.id}}" ng-click="useThisTaskInstead(task)">
    <!--                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       -->
    <!--                                   set this in the
                                             target scope.          --> 
      {{task.name}}</a> ...
```

**I want the target controller to only contact the backend API if the `task` isn't in scope.**

The URL in the address bar should also still show `http://example.org/tasks/5`, for example.

**UPDATE**

Something I tried which I'm unsure about:

I have a top-level `ApplicationController` in which I define:

```
$scope.cacheTask: function (task) {
  $scope.task = task;
};
```

...and then the link becomes:

```
<a href="/tasks/{{task.id}}" ng-click="cacheTask(task)">
```

...and in my `TaskController`:

```
    if (typeof $scope.task !== 'undefined'  && $scope.task.id == $routeParams.id) {
        // nothing to do -- task already set in scope.
        console.log("task already in scope");
    } else {
        console.log("fetching task");
        // load task
        $q.when(taskService.get($routeParams.id).$promise).then(function(task) {
            console.log("task fetched from backend", task);
            // set the task in scope
            $scope.task = task;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be handled in your model/persistence system. Your model access layer's API should abstract the caching away, and the controllers/views can get on with life (any use of `$scope` for non-presentational stuff is a bit of a smell IMHO).

Controllers and views should be completely ignorant of persistence state. Have them use a method like `Task.get(id)` than returns a promise. Clean, and the rest of your app is none the wiser whether the promise was fulfilled from cache or a fresh HTTP request.

Comment: Right, so instead of getting ```cacheTask``` to set the scope, it sets a cache field on the task service singleton, which is then checked with every call to ```taskService.get(id)```?

Comment: Yes - if `task` is a data access layer (or an ActiveRecord-y thing). Otherwise it'd be handled in the persistence layer. Both `$http` and $resource` have really simple ways of enabling caching.

Comment: BTW - no need to suffix a service with Service (or `Factory` etc) - services are a concept for ng's module system, not something to put into your naming.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the caching feature. I'll see if it's easy to pre-populate the cache with the ```cacheTask``` concept I discuss in my answer.