# Pre-populating the AngularJS $resource cache

Tags: angularjs

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357120/angularjs-and-linked-resources-getting-from-scope-if-exists) highlighted caching possibilities in my services.

The [documentation for ngResource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)  (*v1.3.0-build.2417 (snapshot)* at the time of writing this) shows a `cache` flag.

**However**, the cache will only be populated after the first call to `service.get(id)`. I want to be able to pre-populate the resource cache with an item that was retrieved from elsewhere

*(It's perfectly reasonable to have the same item be available from 2+ endpoints. E.g. you can have a task available at `/task/5` and as part of a collection at `/projects/99/tasks` if task 5 is part of project 99)*

I've tried this, but it is very ugly:

```
// return the API in the project service
return {
        project: null, // my own hand-rolled cache

        get: function (id) {

            // check cache
            if (this.project != null && this.project.id == id) {
                console.log("Returning CACHED project", this.project);
                var future = $q.defer();
                future.resolve(this.project);
                // UGLY: for consistent access in the controller
                future.$promise = future.promise;
                return future;
            } else {
                return Projects.get({
                    id: id
                });
            }
        }, // etc
```

And in the controller:

```
$q.when(projectService.get($routeParams.id).$promise).then(function(project) {
  // etc
```

**How do I pre-populate the cache using AngularJS idioms?**

Answer (score 0):

You can put the cache value manually into the cache factory.  Inject $cacheFactory, get the http cache, and put the object into the cache with the key being the path of the resource.

For example:

```
var task = { 
    // ... task object here ... 
};

var httpCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
httpCache.put('/projects/99/tasks/5', task);
httpCache.put('/task/5', task);
```

One thing to note, if you set the cache flag in your resource to true, it'll default to use the $http cache.  You can also set it to a custom cacheFactory instance.  In that case, you'd just put the value to your custom cache instead.